# Frechet Derivative simple application

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, random-variables, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

Suppose that $X$ is a square integrable random variable, i.e. $X\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and the function $g:L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where 
$$g(X(\omega))=-\alpha X(\omega)^2+\beta X(\omega)$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$ are positive constants. Could someone apply the Frechet derivative to this function and if yes how what is the method to do it? I am trying to understand what is the difference between Frechet derivative and the classic one that we use from our school years and how can we apply it. I only know that in Banach spaces we can use the Frechet derivative and since $L^2$ is a Banach space I want to know how can this derivative de implemented in my case

Comment: Would it be helpful to re-state my problem? and how?

Comment: I don't know any probability theory, and I'm not familiar with the notation you're using, so I hesitate to comment, but as no-one else has done so, I'll say that a couple of things don't look right. If $X^2\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R},$ $\omega\mapsto X(\omega)^2$ (I don't know what else $X^2$ could mean), then surely there is no reason to suppose that $X^2$ is square integrable? (E.g. $\Omega=(0,1),$ $X(\omega)=\omega^{-1/4}.$) So you can't mean $g(X)\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}).$ Indeed, you imply $g(X)\in\mathbb{R}.$ But how can it be the case that $X^2\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley, well I can not say that I am sure for the details that i define...I am simply a begginer and I try to learn...I am trying to understand what you are talking about and it seems resonable to me...Cay you help me define the problem in a right way?

Comment: It also baffles me that even if you mean something like $g(X)=-\alpha\int_\Omega X^2+\beta\int_\Omega X+\gamma\in\mathbb{R},$ there is no reason to believe that $\int_\Omega X$ is defined, e.g. if $\Omega=(0,\infty)$ and $X(\omega)=1/\omega.$

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley Ok so what do you propose? How should I correct this?

Comment: I see you've now edited the question, but the edit has introduced two new mysteries. (1) How does $g$ take values in $\mathbb{R}^2$? (2) What is $\omega$ in the definition of $g(X)$? Clearly it is a point of $\Omega,$ but *which* point?

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley I don't now...I give up...Is it so difficult to define something? How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to define the function $g:L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\to L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ such that $g(X)=-\alpha X^2+\beta X$.
Since $X$ is a random variable, I assume that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space, then we have $L^2\subseteq L^1$. Let's see that $g$ is well defined, that is, $g(X)\in L^1$ when $X\in L^2$. Indeed $$\int_\Omega|g(X)|d\mathbb{P}\leq\alpha\int_\Omega|X|^2d\mathbb{P}+\beta\int_\Omega|X|d\mathbb{P}<\infty.$$
The integrals are finite because $X\in L^2\subseteq L^1$.

Let's compute the Fréchet derivative. Let $X,H\in L^2$ be random variables, then
\begin{align}g(X+H)&=-\alpha(X+H)^2+\beta(X+H)\\
&=-\alpha X^2+\beta X-2\alpha HX+\beta H-\alpha H^2\\
&=g(X)+(\beta-2\alpha X)H-\alpha H^2.\end{align}

Notice that the map $L:L^2\to L^1$ given by $L(H)=(\beta-2\alpha X)H$ is clearly linear. Let's prove that is continuous:
\begin{align}
\|(\beta-2\alpha X)H\|_{L^1}&\leq\int_\Omega|\beta-2\alpha X|\cdot|H|d\mathbb{P}\\
&\leq\beta\int_\Omega|H|d\mathbb{P}+2\alpha\int_\Omega|XH|d\mathbb{P}\\
&\leq\beta\|H\|_{L^1}+2\alpha\|X\|_{L^1}\|H\|_{L^1}\\
&\leq\left(\beta+2\alpha\|X\|_{L^1}\right)\|H\|_{L^2}
\end{align}
where the third inequality is because of Holder inequality and the last inequality is because of Cauchy-Schwarz $$\|H\|_{L^1}=\int_\Omega|H|d\mathbb{P}\leq\left(\int_\Omega d\mathbb{P}\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_\Omega H^2d\mathbb{P}\right)^{1/2}=\|H\|_{L^2}.$$

Lastly, let's check that $-\alpha H^2\in o(\|H\|_{L^2})$. Since $\|-\alpha H^2\|_{L^1}\leq\alpha\int_\Omega H^2d\mathbb{P}\leq\alpha\|H\|_{L^2}^2$, then $$\frac{\|-\alpha H^2\|_{L^1}}{\|H\|_{L^2}}\leq\|H\|_{L^2}\xrightarrow{\|H\|_{L^2}\to 0}{0}.$$

With all this we have $g(X+H)=g(X)+L(H)+o(\|H\|_{L^2})$ and conclude that $g$ is Fréchet differentiable in $X$ and $$Dg(X)=(\beta-2\alpha X)\in\mathcal{L}(L^2,L^1).$$